# Ext JS 4.0 Modifying view does not modify the output in browser. Please help

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am new to Ext JS, so pardon my ignorance, but I seem to be having basic problem here.
I am trying to execute the simple example of Account Manager provided at Ext JS 4.0 site for MVC architecture. Unlike the example, my form fields names must not change.

In this example: if I change xtype to label, it still displays a textfield that I can modify. Also If i change the fieldLabel and name of items to "property", it does not show on the browser.Am I missing something here -- modifying the view does not modify the output I see in browser?Please suggest what xtype I must use. I do not see a working form example on Ext JS site that is in 4.0 version, Please provide me one.

```
Ext.define('AM.view.user.Edit', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias : 'widget.useredit',

    title : 'Edit User',
    layout: 'fit',
    autoShow: true,

    initComponent: function() {
        this.items = [
            {
                xtype: 'form',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name : '**name**',
                        fieldLabel: 'Name'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name : 'email',
                        fieldLabel: 'Email'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];

        this.buttons = [
            {
                text: 'Save',
                action: 'save'
            },
            {
                text: 'Cancel',
                scope: this,
                handler: this.close
            }
        ];

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: Just a suggestion. Maybe your javascript files were hardly cached by browser. Try to clean cache.

Comment: Thanks Molecule but I already did that, still no use! Even the text "save" when changed to 'something', does not display it on browser!

Comment: This is a caching issue, period. either on the server side or client side. use firebug to see if the particular JS file is requested from the server and if yes, its contents.

Answer (score 0):

Show the actual code that creates an instance of your class, you are *defining* it, not creating a new instance (with Ext.create for example). Where *arguments* variable come from in line:

```
this.callParent(arguments)
```

Sorry I am not able to post this as a comment, I don't have enough *reputation*.